# Cant create a spot instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ec2-spot-market

I am trying to launch an EC2 t2.micro spot instance.
When finishing to configure it, I try to launch it and I get an error
saying [image]

I don't have even a single EC2 instance running, am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: If you access the **Limits** section in the left navigation menu, what does it show for your Spot Instance limits? [Spot Instance Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console) says "By default, there is an account limit of 20 Spot Instances per region". Are there currently any other spot instances in that account and region?

Comment: None.
I am a free tier user, but I did not find anywhere anything saying that there is a problem with that.

Comment: What does it show for "Spot instance requests" in the **Limits** screen? The fact you are using the Free Usage Tier has no impact on your usage of the service — it is merely a pricing discount.

Comment: `Spot instance requests` -> default

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your account is rather new and some automated fraud protection has kicked-in.

From [Spot Instance Limits - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html):

> **Spot Request Limits**
>
> When your account is new, your limit might be lower than 20 to start, but increase over time. In addition, your account might have limits on specific Spot Instance types. If you submit a Spot Instance request and you receive the error Max spot instance count exceeded, you can complete the AWS Support Center [Create Case](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-ec2-spot-instances) form to request an Amazon EC2 instance limit increase. For **Use Case Description**, indicate that you need an increase in your limits for Spot Instance requests.